# In spark , if I want to connect two pairs ,and the pair value is DenseMatrix ,what should I do?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

For example:

```
Input: RDD[arraySeq((arraySeq(1),DenseMatrix(2,3)), (arraySeq(2),DenseMatrix(5,7)), (arraySeq(4),DenseMatrix(7,8)), ((arraySeq(1),DenseMatrix(10,23)))]
Output: RDD[(double(1), Vector(2,3,10,23)), (double(2), Vector(5,7)), (double(4), Vector(7,8))]
```

I have searched "combineByKey , reduceByKey", they seems able to work on this problem ,but I don't know how to write the code.

Besides, if the input is:

`arraySeq( (arraySeq(1),DenseMatrix(2,3)), (arraySeq(2),DenseMatrix(5,7)), (arraySeq(4),DenseMatrix(7,8)), ((arraySeq(1),DenseMatrix(10,23)) )`,

which means the input is not a RDD, what should I do if I want to get the ouput:

`(double(1), DenseVector(2,3,10,23)),  (double(2), DenseVector(5,7)),  (double(4), DenseVector(7,8))`,     and the output is not RDD too.

Comment: Please let me know if you are looking for some other answer than answer I posted.

Comment: Hi , so sorry for my unclear type definition, I have changed my question, the type of input and output are  prescribed, so maybe your answer is not that suitable,  can you help me with the new question?

Comment: No Problem, I am working on your problem now , I'll get back to you once I found solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
val pairs = List((1,Seq(2,3)), (2,Seq(5,7)), (4,Seq(7,8)), ((1,Seq(10,23))))
val pairsRdd = sc.parallelize(pairs)
pairsRdd.reduceByKey((a,b)=>a++b).collect
```

Output:

```
res0: Array[(Int, Seq[Int])] = Array((1,List(2, 3, 10, 23)), (2,List(5, 7)), (4,List(7, 8)))
```

Comment: Maybe the OP was looking for tuple instead of a seq. The type being like this: `Array[(Int, (Int,Int,Int,Int))]`

Comment: Sorry for my unclear type definition, I've changed the input and output tuple type